# Laravel 5.4.36 - post routing issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm using Xampp and Laravel and my app is throwing the following error while I'm trying to make a post route:

#### ERROR

> Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\HandleClient::validate() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)

**Form**

```
<form action="{{route('handle')}}" method="POST">
    <label for="cn">Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cn" placeholder="Customer Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Request"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token" />
</form>
```

**Controller `HandleClient.php`**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HandleClient extends Controller
{       
    public function validate(Request $request){
        return view('finish',$request);
    }   
}
```

**`web.php` routes file**:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
Route::post('/Request_handled',[
    'uses'  => 'HandleClient@validate',
    'as'    => 'handle'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the base Controller class uses`ValidatesRequests` which provides a validate function to the Controller class. Naming your function `validate` overrides this function.

Rename your function from `validate` to something else and update your route, then you shouldn't have a conflict anymore.

Comment: that helped already,, but I got this error after this solution {Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$startSection}

Comment: Can you show us the blade file for your view called "finish"?